# Disabling Chromium XFCE Power Management Inhibition

Tags: xfce, power-management, screensaver, chrome

For a long time I've been having problems with my Screen Saver not working properly, now it seems it tells me the problem in the XFCE4 Panel's Power Manager Plugin

[image: xfce power manager plugin]

Captain reads

> `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser` is currently inhibiting power management

It seems specifically that a backgrounded tab of Reuters is doing it

- https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-immigration-children-idUSKBN0EK1VM20140609

How do I disable this most annoying "feature" of chromium-browser

When I run `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon --debug`, I get in the output,

> TRACE[xfpm-inhibit.c:405] xfpm_inhibit_inhibit(): Inhibit send application name=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser reason=WebRTC has active PeerConnections sender=:1.628

External links

- [Reddit post of someone having the same problem with chrome using dbus to send inhibit message](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4pvxx3/dbus_policy_to_deny_chrome_from_inhibiting_power/)
- [Google Product Forum post on this problem](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/EZpNDL4GzyU;context-place=forum/chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is a verified bug without a patch yet, Launchpad Bug 1600622](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1600622)

One solution that is far from ideal is to block all advertisements with [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en). Chrome can still inhibit the screensaver, but in this case it seems that whatever is responsible isn't getting through.

Specifically the problem seems to be with **GoogleTagServices.com** which pulls in [this script](https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js). If that's blocked by uBlock Origin, you're good and you won't have Power Management Inhibition. If that's not blocked, you'll have problems.

Comment: Any webcrt session chrome://webrtc-internals will cause xfce4-power-manager, xscreensaver, light-locker to not work. Mine was a problem problem with ebay's sign in script. I don't know if theres any solution besides manually locking the screen.

Comment: It's 2019 and I saw identical lines just now... I don't even care why this happens anymore, this is the last nail in the coffin for google and google chrome for me.

@MeowMeow the obvious solution is cutting out the direct cause, which is exactly what I'm going to do right now. Trying to prevent programs from fucking the system up isn't something anyone should be busy doing.

Answer (score 0):

ublock example didn't solve my issue. The only fix I could find was to uninstall gnome-screensaver and install xscreensaver. So far this fix seems to be working.

Comment: I'm not using screen saver, and the problem (with me) according to the power manager is `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser` what does your power manager say the problem is?

Comment: Not sure; i run xfce on top of ubuntu (not xubuntu); I saw your note above but i didn't see any option with power manager to show what is blocking it. There is one problem i still have with xscreensaver. Occasionally the display won't wake up and I'm forced to reboot - this bug also existed in 16.0 but eventually they fixed it and it went away. I also had to swap gdm3 to lightdm as gdm3 would crash when i tried to open a virtual console.--- If you give me the command to query powermanager as to what is blocking it i will check.

Comment: I had a similar informational error in XFCE Power Manager with `brave-browser` (based on `chromium`) - uninstalling `xfce-screensaver` fixed the message & power management

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue and where adjusting the brightness of a screen is not possibly for any reason, an alternative workaround is to use `redshift` to lower the screen brightness:

```
redshift -b 0.7:0.4 -m randr -o -t 5500K:3500K
```